# Layout Binding integer value limit from 0 to 10 in android with databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, int, onclicklistener, android-databinding

I am trying to set the limit of an integer with a minimum value of 0 and maximum of 10 in android with the help of databinding.
For that i have a bindable adapter which set the value of an integer with two listener one increase the value and the other decrease it. Now finally i wanted to set the limit of that integer, minimum of 0 and maximum of 10.

```
@BindingAdapter("quantity")
public static void setQuantityText(TextView textView, int quantity) {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
}
public static class ListenerIncrease implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FragmentBinding binding;

    public ListenerIncrease(FragmentBinding binding) {
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int quantity = binding.getQuantity();
        binding.setQuantity(++quantity);
    }
}
public static class ListenerDecrease implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FragmentBinding binding;

    public ListenerDecrease(FragmentBinding binding) {
        this.binding = binding;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int quantity = binding.getQuantity();
        binding.setQuantity(--quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you handle the clicks a little differently. The lambda expression part only works in Android Studio 2.1 and above.

```
<Button android:onClick="@{(view)->Handlers.increment(view, 10)}" .../>
<Button android:onClick="@{(view)->Handlers.decrement(view, 0)}" .../>
<TextView app:quantity="@{quantity}"/>
```

And then your handler class has:

```
public static void increment(View view, int max) {
    FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view);
    binding.setQuantity(Math.max(max, binding.getQuantity() + 1));
}

public static void decrement(View view, int min) {
    FragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view);
    binding.setQuantity(Math.min(min, binding.getQuantity() - 1));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use full-blown two-way binding. In the forthcoming Android Studio 2.2, you'll be able to do this:

```
<Button android:onClick="@{()->Handlers.increment(quantityView, 10)}" .../>
<Button android:onClick="@{()->Handlers.decrement(quantityView, 0)}" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/quantityView" app:quantity="@={`` + quantity}"/>
```

And then your handler class has:

```
private static int getCurrentIntValue(TextView view) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(view.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
public static void increment(TextView view, int max) {
    int value = getCurrentIntValue(view);
    binding.setQuantity(Math.max(max, value + 1));
}

public static void decrement(View view, int min) {
    int value = getCurrentIntValue(view);
    binding.setQuantity(Math.min(min, value - 1));
}
```

The trick added in Android Studio 2.2 is the support for the conversions for string concatenation with empty string. It is a useful shortcut. Without that (Android Studio 2.1), you'll need to add your own two-way binding for integer-to-TextView text:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "quantity")
public static int getQuantity(TextView view) {
    return getCurrentIntValue(view);
}
```

and here's a simplified binding adapter. Use the one in TextViewBindingAdapter.java as a template if you need to add text watchers to the same TextView:

```
@BindingAdapter("onQuantityChanged")
public static void setQuanityWatcher(TextView view,
        final InverseBindingListener quantityChanged) {
    TextWatcher newTextWatcher;
    if (quantityChanged == null) {
        newTextWatcher = null;
    } else {
        newTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                quantityChanged.onChange();
            }
            // others are empty...
        }
    }
    TextWatcher oldTextWatcher = ListenerUtil.trackListener(
        view, newTextWatcher, R.id.textWatcher);
    if (oldTextWatcher != null) {
        view.removeTextChangeListener(oldTextWatcher);
    }
    if (newTextWatcher != null) {
        view.addTextChangedListener(newTextWatcher);
    }
 }
```

Note that I haven't compiled any of this, so there may be typos.

Comment: msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. view is missing ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: That means that you are using "Identifiers" without importing the type.

Comment: I was importing the view <import type="com.xyz.www.fragment"/>  but still its shows the error.  Is I am importing the right view

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and add the layout

Comment: George  I am importing the view with <import type="android.view.View"/> but still it throws the error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. view is missing it

Comment: It seems that you are using 'view' not 'View' based on the error message.